# invalid xml validation using XDocument or XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I try to validate a xml file against a xsd.

I found these two versions to achieve that:

- [Using XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.extensions.validate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_Schema_Extensions_Validate_System_Xml_Linq_XDocument_System_Xml_Schema_XmlSchemaSet_System_Xml_Schema_ValidationEventHandler_)
- [Using XmlReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.validationeventargs.severity?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_Schema_ValidationEventArgs_Severity)

I tried both but none of them is working correctly.

The simplyfied code that I was using is:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Schema;

public class Test
{
    #region Xsd
    public const string Xsd = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<schema xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" targetNamespace=""http://www.sample.de/Testing"" xmlns:tns=""http://www.sample.de/Testing"" elementFormDefault=""qualified"">
    <element name=""root"">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name=""Version"">
                    <simpleType>
                        <restriction base=""string"">
                            <enumeration value=""V1""></enumeration>
                        </restriction>
                    </simpleType>
                </element>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>";
    #endregion

    public const string InvalidXml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<IdentificationInData xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Toolkit.Common.Data"">
  <Args xmlns=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Toolkit.Common.Data"">/NoiseDuration=Seconds2 /Philosophy=Distance /SamplingRate=10</Args>
</IdentificationInData>";

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsValidUsingXDocument(null));
        Console.WriteLine(IsValidUsingXDocument("http://www.sample.de/Testing"));

        Console.WriteLine(IsValidUsingXmlReader(null));
        Console.WriteLine(IsValidUsingXmlReader("http://www.sample.de/Testing"));
    }

    public static bool IsValidUsingXDocument(string schemaNamespace)
    {
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.extensions.validate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_Schema_Extensions_Validate_System_Xml_Linq_XDocument_System_Xml_Schema_XmlSchemaSet_System_Xml_Schema_ValidationEventHandler_

        using (var xsdContentReader = new StringReader(Xsd))
        using (var xsdReader = XmlReader.Create(xsdContentReader))
        using (var databaseContentReader = new StringReader(InvalidXml))
        {
            var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
            schemas.Add(schemaNamespace, xsdReader);

            try
            {
                var result = true;

                var doc = XDocument.Load(databaseContentReader);
                doc.Validate(schemas, (_, __) => result = false);
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool IsValidUsingXmlReader(string schemaNamespace)
    {
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.validationeventargs.severity?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_Schema_ValidationEventArgs_Severity

        using (var xsdContentReader = new StringReader(Xsd))
        using (var xsdReader = XmlReader.Create(xsdContentReader))
        {
            var result = true;

            var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Schemas.Add(schemaNamespace, xsdReader);
            settings.ValidationEventHandler += (_, __) => result = false;
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

            using (var databaseContentReader = new StringReader(InvalidXml))
            using (var validatingReader = XmlReader.Create(databaseContentReader, settings))
            {
                while (validatingReader.Read())
                {
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is runnable for testing at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/leNBW8

**The problem is that the xsd and the xml are completely different and the validation should fail - but didn't.** Not even the root tag matches.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @GSerg Are you trying to tell me that an XSD that contains namespaces and enforces a special root element matches an XML that does not have any of this, just because the elements in the XML have a different namespace? What is the meaning of an Xsd validation in that case? In that case I take a Xml file from a completely different application/source and this will be valid against MY xsd?!?!?!?

Comment: No, it means that XSD validates elements, not documents, like the accepted answer explains. Your document does not have any elements that the schema can validate, so it does not raise an error (but it does not say it is validated either). You need to validate, then double check that, even in the absence of validation callbacks, `doc.SchemaInfo.Validity` is `XmlSchemaValidity.Valid`. `In that case I take a Xml file from a completely different application/source and this will be valid against MY xsd?` - yes, that is exactly the problem described in the duplicate question.

Comment: @GSerg Maybe I can live with the fact that tags are ignored that contain there own namespace but the Xsd has required tag that are missing in the xml. In that case the validation has to fail. I used `xsd.exe` to read the file after I validated it. If the validation works parsing has to work too.

Comment: It is not about namespace. You can have the same namespace and the file will still not raise validation errors if the root element is not recognized by its local name. `The Xsd has required tag that are missing in the xml` - no, the XSD describes an element called `root`. If there is an element called `root` in the document, it will be validated against the XSD. XSD cannot declare that this `root` element has to be the root of the document. `But in my case parsing fails` - that does not make sense, you can only pass to validation documents that have successfully parsed.

Comment: @GSerg _that does not make sense, you can only pass to validation documents that have successfully parsed_ Sorry I checkt the document against XSD. After that I used a XmlSerializer with types generated out of XSD to read the content and I got an exception. Sorry having this information XSD-validation is completely useless. Thx for clearification. The only working way is try parsing the document and catch exceptions.

Comment: `The only working way is try parsing the document and catch exceptions` - no, the correct way is to validate against the schema and then check if `doc.SchemaInfo.Validity` is `XmlSchemaValidity.Valid`.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you very much. That last post you did was the hint that I was looking for.

Comment: I actually said that [in the first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55703177/invalid-xml-validation-using-xdocument-or-xmlreader?noredirect=1#comment98088842_55703177) and just repeated later.